# Use row object in onFetch (BIRT)

Tags: javascript, report, birt

I have a generel question.

I want to use the row object in BIRT in the onFetch section of a dataset.

[image: Palette Window in BIRT]

But it does not work. I just get the following error:

[image: Errormessage]

Is it not possible to use the row object in onFetch of a dataset? Which is the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the values of the current row in the onFetch event with the syntax 
"row[column_name]".

For example (assuming you have a logging framework), you can do this:

```
log.info("dataSet=" + row.dataSet);
var columnDefns = row.dataSet.getColumnDefns();
var arrayLength = columnDefns.length;
for (var i=0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
    var colname = columnDefns[i].name;
    log.info(colname + "=" + row[colname]);
}
```